# QListView displaying blank rows ?? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qabstractlistmodel

I have just started experimenting with Qt's AbstractListModel and as a practice application Im trying to make a model which will store custom objects.The classes are `testperson`, `personlistmodel` class and `mainwindow`. The problem im having is that my view isnt displaying the correct data, if I add two 'testperson's then my listView displays two empty rows. So can someone please guide me on how the data formatting of model to view actually works ??? what am i doing wrong now ??

Person Class.cpp

```
testPerson::testPerson(const QString &name, QObject *parent):QObject (parent)
{
  this->fName = name;
  connect(this,SIGNAL(pesonAdd()),this,SLOT(personConfirm()));
  emit pesonAdd();
}

void testPerson::setPerson(QString setTo)
{
  fName = setTo;
}

QString testPerson::getPerson() const
{
  return fName;
}


void testPerson::personConfirm()
{
qDebug() << fName << QTime::currentTime().toString();
}
```

PersonListModel.h

```
class personListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit personListModel(QObject *parent = 0);
  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
  bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
  Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
  //Custom functions
  void addPerson(testPerson &person);
private:
  QList<testPerson*> dataStore;
};
```

PersonListModel.cpp

```
personListModel::personListModel(QObject *parent): QAbstractListModel (parent)
{
}

int personListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  return dataStore.count();
}

QVariant personListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if(role != Qt::DisplayRole || role != Qt::EditRole){
    return QVariant();
  }

  if(index.column() == 0 && index.row() < dataStore.count() ){
    return QVariant(dataStore[index.row()]->getPerson());
  }else{
    return QVariant();
  }

}

bool personListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
  if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {

    testPerson *item = dataStore[index.row()];
    item->setPerson(value.toString());

    dataStore.at(index.row())->setPerson(value.toString());
    emit dataChanged(index,index);
    return true;
 }
 return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags personListModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  if(!index.isValid()){
    return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
  }
  return Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
}

void personListModel::addPerson(testPerson &person)
{
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),dataStore.count(), dataStore.count());
  dataStore.append(&person);
  endInsertRows();
}
```

Heres some test code in the mainWindow.cpp

```
// Inc needed files 

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  //Test model
  personListModel *model = new personListModel(this);
  testPerson one("Adam Smith",this);
  testPerson two("John Smith",this);
  model->addPerson(one);
  model->addPerson(two);
  ui->listView->setModel(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code you've provided is correct, you are declaring your `testPerson` objects on the stack then storing them as pointers inside the model.  The surprising thing is that this isn't causing a crash.

Comment: So the model is storing invalid pointers ?? Since the `testPerson` objects are released when out of scope, and is that why its showing empty rows...sorry so its not with my `personlistmodel` functions ??

Comment: I can't say for sure, but that's the obvious thing that your sample code is doing wrong.